# AppCache for 24 hours?

Tags: html, cordova, local-storage, html5-appcache

Recently I started using the

```
<html manifest="cache.appcache">
```

method for storing assets in my PhoneGap application.

Is it possible to use appcache but have it check every 24 hours for an updated version of the cached items?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do so you have to generate the `cache.appcache` dynamically and add a comment line which changes in the desired interval:

```
    CACHE MANIFEST
    # 2012-07-31 14:30

    css/default.css
    ...
```

and after 24 hours:

```
    CACHE MANIFEST
    # 2012-08-01 14:30

    css/default.css
    ...
```

If changes in the content of that file happens a browser loads all cached data again.

NOTE: just a touch in file system does not bring the expected result. The content itself has to change.

http://appcachefacts.info/

Answer (score 1):

you could set the expire datetime of the manifest on the

```
.htaccess
```

like this:

```
ExpiresByType text/cache-manifest "access plus 24 hours"
```

Comment: this will not cause the AppCache to update. According to specification it only has to update if the content of the manifest will change.

Comment: what this will do is that the manifest wont be cached... I had a problem with this because even when I changed the manifest the browser didn't notice the changes.

Comment: Then you have to set expire to actual. Your approach will cause that the manifest will be cached and only become updated in 24h. But that will cause that an available update of the app will wait until the manifest is updated before it becomes active.